# i'm using 2.4.3-p1 (Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Unable to load theme by specified key: '')

Tags: magento2, theme

[image]

This is the screenshot of error, which i'm facing error while uploading theme without key number.. please help me with this issue..thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please share log details path: var/log/exception.log or debug.log or system.log

Comment: yeah i posted the screenshot of var/log/system.log, thanks for comment on my issue

Comment: It looks like your key is wrong, see this and make changes: https://bssthemes.com/blog/unable-to-load-theme-by-specified-key/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue since there is no theme entry in `core_config_data` table, I inserted the path `design/theme/theme_id` and in the value, placed the Id of my custom theme. Here is the screenshot... after `(cache:flush)` the theme is applied!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating table **design_config_grid_flat** column **theme_theme_id**   Please see the screenshots :

[image]